# getting an error "p5practice.js:97 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, json, canvas

I was working on the paddle part of my code and was fixing other errors and after it was fixed, it gave me this error "p5practice.js:97 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined" Also, if that error can be fixed, how do I properly get my paddle to work? I've looked at several other pong like examples and have had no luck with mine working.

```js
//variables
var canvas;
var ctx;
var w;
var h;
var ball;
var paddle;
var score1;


//ball object
var BALL = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = "white";
    this.radius = 12;
    this.vx = 3;
    this.vy = -3;
};

//paddle 1
var PADDLE = function(x, y) {
    this.x = 10;
    this.y = h/2 - 50;
    this.color = "white";
    this.width = 5;
    this.height = 100;
    
};

window.addEventListener("keydown", movePaddle);
//keydown event

    //down
function movePaddle(e) {
 
        switch (event.keyCode){
          case 38: //up 
          console.log(paddle.y)
          if (paddle.y - 30 >= -10) {
            paddle.y -= 30;
          }
          break;
          case 40: // down 
          console.log(paddle.y)
          if (paddle.y + 30 < 305) {
            paddle.y += 30;
          }
          break;
        }
      }
     

//DOM load
window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ball = new BALL (w/2, h/2);
    paddle = new PADDLE(w-100, h/2);
    drawScore();
    startGame();
    movePaddle(); 
        
    
};
function startGame() {
    requestAnimationFrame(startGame);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ball.x += ball.vx;
    ball.y += ball.vy;

    ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.save();  
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.fillStyle = paddle.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.save();  
    ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 4;  
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4;  
    ctx.shadowColor = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
}
//collision with walls
//https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/paddle-ball/830543654

//bottom
if(ball.y >= 390) {
    ball.vy = -ball.vy;
    console.log("bottom hit");
}
//top
if(ball.y <= 10) {
    ball.vy = -ball.vy;
    console.log("top hit");
}

//right
if (ball.x >= 590){
     ball.vx = -ball.vx;
     console.log("right hit");
}
//left
if(ball.x <= 10){
    score++;
    ball.x = w/2;
    ball.y = h/2;
    console.log("left hit");
}

//collision with paddle
if(ball.x<15){
    if(ball.y>paddle.y && ball.y<paddle.y + paddle.height){
        ball.vy = -ball.vy;
        console.log("paddle");
    }
}

    



//reset
//https://bl.ocks.org/ruffrey/1e242222aebbcd102a53

//not finished
function reset(){
    ball.x;
    ball.y;
}

//score
var score = 0;

function drawScore(){
    ctx.font ="16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle ="#0095DD";
    ctx.fillText("Score: "+score,w/2, 20);

}


var leftScore = this.x > 10;
    if (leftScore){
        playerCount.score++;
    }
    this.reset();
```

```css
canvas {
   border: 3px solid yellow;
   background-color: black;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pong</title>
        <script src="p5practice.js"></script>
        <link rel= 'stylesheet' href="p5practice.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is line 97?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your `if` statements at the bottom into the `onload` or `startGame` function. They are running before the variable `ball` is getting initialized. So you are getting the error that is saying `ball` is `undefined`

You will also need to move this or it will complain about `x`:

```
var leftScore = this.x > 10;
```

```js
//variables
var canvas;
var ctx;
var w;
var h;
var ball;
var paddle;
var score1;


//ball object
var BALL = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.color = "white";
  this.radius = 12;
  this.vx = 3;
  this.vy = -3;
};

//paddle 1
var PADDLE = function(x, y) {
  this.x = 10;
  this.y = h / 2 - 50;
  this.color = "white";
  this.width = 5;
  this.height = 100;

};

window.addEventListener("keydown", movePaddle);
//keydown event

//down
function movePaddle(e) {

  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 38: //up 
      console.log(paddle.y)
      if (paddle.y - 30 >= -10) {
        paddle.y -= 30;
      }
      break;
    case 40: // down 
      console.log(paddle.y)
      if (paddle.y + 30 < 305) {
        paddle.y += 30;
      }
      break;
  }
}


//DOM load
window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  w = canvas.width;
  h = canvas.height;
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ball = new BALL(w / 2, h / 2);
  paddle = new PADDLE(w - 100, h / 2);
  drawScore();
  startGame();
  movePaddle();

  //bottom
  if (ball.y >= 390) {
    ball.vy = -ball.vy;
    console.log("bottom hit");
  }
  //top
  if (ball.y <= 10) {
    ball.vy = -ball.vy;
    console.log("top hit");
  }

  //right
  if (ball.x >= 590) {
    ball.vx = -ball.vx;
    console.log("right hit");
  }
  //left
  if (ball.x <= 10) {
    score++;
    ball.x = w / 2;
    ball.y = h / 2;
    console.log("left hit");
  }

  //collision with paddle
  if (ball.x < 15) {
    if (ball.y > paddle.y && ball.y < paddle.y + paddle.height) {
      ball.vy = -ball.vy;
      console.log("paddle");
    }
  }
};

function startGame() {
  requestAnimationFrame(startGame);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ball.x += ball.vx;
  ball.y += ball.vy;

  ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.save();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.fillStyle = paddle.color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.save();
  ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 4;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4;
  ctx.shadowColor = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(paddle.x, paddle.y, paddle.width, paddle.height);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.restore();
}
//collision with walls
//https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/paddle-ball/830543654







//reset
//https://bl.ocks.org/ruffrey/1e242222aebbcd102a53

//not finished
function reset() {
  ball.x;
  ball.y;
}

//score
var score = 0;

function drawScore() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, w / 2, 20);

  var leftScore = this.x > 10;
  if (leftScore) {
    playerCount.score++;
  }
  this.reset();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pong</title>
  <script src="p5practice.js"></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href="p5practice.css">
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks! would you happen to know why my collision with paddle if statement isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, no I don't. You should probably open another question for that.